# Callback is not a function, angularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, callback, get

```
getStuff: function(stuff, callback) {

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url + "/" + stuff
                cache: true
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                callback(data);
            });

        },
```

I have the above code. I'm using it multiple times throughout my application however when I call this one I am given callback is not a function. the console.log(data); gives back the appropriate objects however. Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the call of `getStuff`

Comment: Isn't it so that you would have to pass the callback to the subfunction .success? By the time the callback is called, there is nothing coupled to it.

Comment: callback is an argument to `getStuff`, so seems that you are not passing in a function to that argument

Comment: The message says it all: you're passing something that is not a function (or you don't pass any callback) to `getStuff()`. That's not a very good way of using promises anyway. You shouldn't pass a callback to getStuf(). Instead, getStuff() should return the promise, and the caller should call then() or success() on the returned promise. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the line where you call getStuff(stuff, callback). My guess is that the second "callback" paramater is not actually a function. After many years of wrestling with frustrating errors I've learned that, when in doubt, the error message is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your second parameter of your **getStuff** function is a **function**. However, you should use promise to handle **$http** request. By definition, **$http** return promise, and use the **$q.defer()** promise manager. It's good practice to use promise and $q.

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http, $q){

    function get(){
      //Use $q.defer() promise manager
      var defer = $q.defer();
      //Create a defer promise
      var promise = defer.promise;

      $http.get('path_to_url').then(function(response){
        //resolve our data
        defer.resolve(response.data);
      });

      //return the promise
      return promise;

    }

    var factory = {
      get: get
    };

    return factory;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service, $q) {

  Service.get().then(function(data){

    //Here your resolve data
    console.log(data);
  })

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

Comment: Your promise code is an anti-pattern: the returned promise is never rejected, even if the http call fails, and it's way too complex. You can simply replace it by `return $http.get('...').then(function(response) {return response.data;});`. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/